# Suppress Child View OnClickListeners

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view, onclicklistener

I have a linear layout that has several views within it. These views may have click listeners already associated with them when they are added to the layout. I want to disable all click listeners for children of this linear layout and have only one listener at the top level.

Comment: please add your code. We can not see your approach unless

Answer (score 0):

As a variant you may go through all child views and make them not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that through the xml by adding the options `focusable` and `clickable` with `false` as values to the child views and with `true` values to the parent.

Another option would be using the same OnClickListener for parent and child views.